# Merging two df without any key

Tags: python, pandas, merge, key

I have two df and want to merge them because I need one df for dashboard. My problem is that my data has no unique key and all the data points are repeating. For example I have df1 like this:

```
Web       Obj
A         ObJA
A         ObjB
B         ObjA
B         ObjD
B         ObjA
```

df2

```
Web       Lab        Cat
A         LabA       F
A         LabB       F
A         LabF       F
A         LabA       F
B         LabG       G
B         LabD       G
```

I want to merge them both but I have no key... I was thinking that I can create Web's each item 6 times as values will not exceed more than 6...  and then add values one by one... the extra Web value show "NaN" So the output would look like this

```
  Web        Lab        Cat            Obj
    A         LabA       F             ObJA
    A         LabB       F             ObjB
    A         LabF       F
    A         LabA       F
    A
    A
    B         LabG       G             ObjA
    B         LabD       G             ObjD
    B                                  ObjA
    B
    B
    B
```

Or any other way... ?

Comment: Is there a reason that LabA and ObJA are on the same row? Understanding the logic behind the result will make it possible to derive a solution

Comment: Because i want to use "Cat" as a filter later on and that's why I must keep them in the same row

Comment: please let me know if my answer is helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `key` column and do the `merge` that way:

```
df2 = (df2.assign(key=df2['Web'] + (df2.groupby('Web').cumcount() + 1).astype(str))
          .merge(df1.assign(key=df1['Web'] + (df1.groupby('Web').cumcount() + 1).astype(str))
          .drop('Web', axis=1),
           on='key', how='outer'))
df2['Web']=df2['Web'].ffill()
df2
Out[1]: 
  Web   Lab  Cat key   Obj
0   A  LabA    F  A1  ObJA
1   A  LabB    F  A2  ObjB
2   A  LabF    F  A3   NaN
3   A  LabA    F  A4   NaN
4   B  LabG    G  B1  ObjA
5   B  LabD    G  B2  ObjD
6   B   NaN  NaN  B3  ObjA
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that there is seemingly no logic to tie the "Lab" and "Obj" columns together, I think it doesn't make sense to put them on the same rows:

```
df = pd.concat([df1.merge(df2[['web','Cat']].drop_duplicates(), on = 'web'),
                df2]).reset_index(drop = True)
print(df)

   web   Obj Cat   Lab
0    A  ObJA   F   NaN
1    A  ObJB   F   NaN
2    B  ObJA   G   NaN
3    B  ObJD   G   NaN
4    B  ObJA   G   NaN
5    A   NaN   F  LabA
6    A   NaN   F  LabB
7    A   NaN   F  LabF
8    A   NaN   F  LabA
9    B   NaN   G  LabG
10   B   NaN   G  LabD
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new column to facilitate the merge:

```
df1["new"] = df1.groupby("Web").size().apply(range).explode().values
df2["new"] = df2.groupby("Web").size().apply(range).explode().values

df_final = df2.merge(df1, on = ["Web","new"], how = "outer")
#  Web   Lab  Cat  new   Obj
#0   A  LabA    F  0.0  ObJA
#1   A  LabB    F  1.0  ObjB
#2   A  LabF    F  2.0   NaN
#3   A  LabA    F  3.0   NaN
#4   B  LabG    G  0.0  ObjA
#5   B  LabD    G  1.0  ObjD
#6   B   NaN  NaN  2.0  ObjA
```

Optionally, you can drop the new column and sort the dataframe:

```
df_final.drop("new", axis = 1).sort_values(by = "Web")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems good but somehow when I applied it in my real dataframe then I lose many "Web" values